# Connect Google Calendar API get empty array result with php

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I'm trying to read my Google Calendar events using PHP and Googles official PHP client library.

I created a `service account` in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0) and it seemed to work, I can connect to the calendar but I get an empty array:

> Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarList Object (
>   [collection_key:protected] => items [internal_gapi_mappings:protected]
>   => Array ( ) [etag] => [itemsType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarListEntry [itemsDataType:protected] =>
>   array [kind] => [nextPageToken] => [nextSyncToken] =>
>   [modelData:protected] => Array ( [error] => Array ( [errors] => Array
>   ( [0] => Array ( [domain] => global [reason] =>
>   insufficientPermissions [message] => Insufficient Permission ) )
>   [code] => 403 [message] => Insufficient Permission ) )
>   [processed:protected] => Array ( ) )

my code:

```
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
session_start();
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secret.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        #$client->setUseObjects(true);
        $cal=new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
        $calendarList=$cal->calendarList->listCalendarList();
        while(true) {
                foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {
                        echo $calendarListEntry;
                }
                $pageToken = $calendarList->getNextPageToken();
                if ($pageToken) {
                        $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
                        $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList($optParams);
                } else {
                        break;
                }
        }
} else {
        $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/google/oauth2callback.php';
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

Can anybody tell me what I do wrong
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are connecting with a Service account.  A service account has its own Google Calendar account which by default does not have any Calendars, and does not by default have access to your Google calendar account.

That is what the following message is telling you:

> Insufficient Permission

If you want to grant the service account access to your Google Calendar you will need to take the service account email address and share your Google calendar with it like you would share it with any other user.

Comment: I have used the Authorized API access (OAuth 2.0) and i create a client ID in the Google Developers Console. what should I do?

Comment: I think you need to read some more.  You say you are using a service account however your code is for Oauth2.   If you want to use that code then you need to create oauth2 credentials in Google developer console type browser.   Then it will pop up and ask you for permission to access the users calendars